# Does a "tiny" Tensorflow / Keras exist which can be executed with AWS Lambda?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, aws-lambda

The Python Tensorflow package is huge and AWS Lambda allows only 250 MB in which you have to bring all resources in a zip file, including all dependencies.

Is it possible to have a "minified" Tensorflow / Keras?

Comment: I don't know about a minified Tensorflow, but you could pack it separately and save in S3. Then program your Lambda to download the TF pack from S3, unpack in the /tmp directory and then import all TF dependencies: `from tmp.tensorflow import (...)`

Comment: @RenatoByrro That might work... excluding the tensorflow stuff, I use about 60MB of memory. Lambda can currently be increased up to 3GB of Memory.

Comment: It works with other libraries. Never tried with TF, but it should work. In case you give it a try, it would be nice to have your results shared here, there's got to be other people trying the same thing and could be helpful. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by using serverless framework with [serverless-ephemeral](https://github.com/Accenture/serverless-ephemeral)

A specifc tensorflow packager is included